# PHP Namespacing/Design Question

Tags: php, design-patterns, namespaces

I'm currently writing a little library for detecting "bad" words in content (see [here](https://github.com/StephenMelrose/badwords-php)), and I'm having a little trouble deciding how/where to namespace a specific class.

The usage flow of my library so far is as follows,

```
$dictionary = new Dictionary\Csv('/path/to/file.csv');
$config = new Filter\Config\Standard();
$filter = new Filter($dictionary, $config);
```

Basically you create a `Dictionary` of words, a `Filter\Config` which defines how the `Filter` executes, and then create a `Filter` from said objects.

Internally, the `Filter` uses the `Filter\Config` to convert the `Word`s in the `Dictionary` to regular expressions.

**Now my problem** is I don't know what to call and/or where to put this "converter".

My current ideas are,

1. `Word\RegExpConverter` (as there is a `Word` class to represent a word)
2. `Word\Converter\RegExp`
3. `Filter\RegExpConverter`

Because the `Word` is being converted, it seems to make sense to have it in the `Word\` namespace, but at the same time it's something specific to the `Filter` and requires the `Filter\Config`.

Thoughts? Ideas?

Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [timdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172588/timdev)'s answer and some reflection, he was right in that I was trying to over abstract my architecture.

I will only ever want to convert a `Word` into a regular expression. If I were going to convert into multiple formats, I would then introduce converters and inject them.

And because the `Filter\Config` exists to define how that regular expression should be generated, it only makes sense that that's where the logic should reside.

So my implementation will be,

```
$config->generateRegExp($word);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So you've got a class called `Word` that `Filter` consumes (via the converter)?

You may be overdoing it -- first, consider just having Filter consume Words and convert them internally.  If you have no plans to reuse the regex-conversion functionality elsewhere, and you have no concrete plans to provide an alternative converter to be used in place of the RegExConverter, there's not a good reason to stick it in it's own class.

It seems like providing some other (non-RegEx) converter is more likely.

If that's the case, that should be a hint.  Perhaps something like this would be appropriate:

```
Filter\WordConverter\RegEx
Filter\WordConverter\Magic
Filter\WordConverter\AbstractWordConverter (or maybe I'm just an interface?)
```

Comment: First `Filter` checks if there is a cache of the regular expressions. If there isn't, it uses `getWords()` on the `Dictionary` to get the `Word` objects. This is where I become unsure. Using the `Config`, the `Filter` converts the `Word`s into a regular expressions. I can do that internally inside Filter, but it just seems "wrong", as it's not the `Filter`'s job? I go get your point though, maybe I'm over architecting(?) this.

Comment: This sounds even worse, but I'm keen to get someone else's opinion. What do you think to `$config->getRegExp($word)`? As the `Config`'s role is to literally define how the regular expression will be built, and maybe 1 or two rules that apply to the `Filter` itself.